# Does an ADO.NET DataReader read a whole row, or does it only read the columns you "Get"?

Tags: ado.net

If I do something like this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TBL"))
{
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string s = reader.GetString(7);
        }
    }
}
```

does the Read() call read the entire row into memory, or does the GetString(7) call mean that the reader only ever reads the data in column 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it reads the whole row on the read operation.

Comment: Is there anything in ADO.NET that doesn't read the whole row, or does everything have to be limited by the columns included in the SELECT statement?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: the latter; that's kind of the point of specifying the columns in the select statement!

Comment: I agree with Steven, you should only specify the columns that you want

Comment: What I really want to do is reference columns by ordinal in the select statement, something like "SELECT 0, 1, 7 FROM TBL" to only select the first, second and eighth columns. This is not possible, it seems.

Comment: You can't do that in the sql, but you can in the reader... once you've read the whole row, of course.

Comment: @Joel: reading the whole row is what I'm trying to avoid. The table has 1000 columns.

Comment: wow - it sounds like your database design needs to be addressed!

Answer (score 1):

The read operation reads the whole row. The size of the row is determined by your select statement. So, if you have a thousand columns and only want 4, you can do that in your select. If on the otherhand, you want 5 columns if column 1 is Y and 8 columns if it is N, then your out of luck, that can't be done with a single `select * from table`.

The reason it can't be done is that the call to the database sends back a stream of data (the resultset) as fast as it can, there's no further communication between the two, and even if there was, it would have to be on UNSENT rows as the current row would have already been sent and received. To do what you are talking about would require two way communication on every column, which would kill performance except in truly exceptional circumstances. Doing that even on row basis would typically be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the [ExecuteScalar](http://www.devguru.com/features/tutorials/AdoNet/AdoNet3.asp) method of the datareader and you want to specify your columns in your sql command.